# How to add text to existing text in a R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to add text to an existing text in a data.frame in R.

The text in the column is "**icecream**" and I want to add "**_2017**".
The result should be "**icecream_2017**".

Can you help me solving this problem?

Thx a lot!

Max

P.S.: Please excuse the bad layout. Thats my first question in the forum.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a data.frame matching your description:

```
ic_df <- data.frame(var = "icecream")
```

Using `paste0()` we can concatenate strings. `paste0()` is a convenience function, that concatenates strings with no separator.

```
ic_df$var <- paste0(ic_df$var, "_2017")
```